# How to save SQL Server query names

Tags: sql-server

Super simple question. I can find a tonne of info on Alias' and related topics but that's not quite what I'm looking for. When I write up a query, regardless of what it is, I'd like to store it for future use as a local SQL file, for future reference. I'm not looking for much just is there an international or globally accepted standard for naming these files? I can't seem to find it without coming across stored procs, alias' etc. which is not what I think I'm looking for.

Will admittedly I'm not 'new' to SQL been dabbling for years but not in a team structure. Just by myself building queries, as I needed them.  So I know a lot of basics.  I'm not officially trained in it.  So this may or may not be the best way for storing SQL code. If it isn't please advise but otherwise my naming convention so far has been

FUNCTION_TARGETDB_TARGETTABLE(S)_C|R|U|D_BRIEFDESC.sql

So for example
QueryCreatorOfPasswordVars_DB1_Tables123ON456_R_returnUsernaamesForPasswordRecordsWithValuesInThemForInspection.sql

maybe I'm overthinking but thought I'd shout to the webs for some guidance on naming standards

Comment: Call the files what ever you want to. Naming standards are normally set by the company you work for (or yourself if for your own work). Just name them something that is meaningful to you.

Comment: I would be cautious about really long file names.  Windows has limitations on the total length a file name plus path can be.  You could make the file inaccessible.

Comment: "I'd like to store it for future use" (sic).  You do know that's also what the database itself does?  You could use generate scripts to get back all the queries you ever wrote, and there's no danger that you missed edits that someone else made.  If you don't have a source control system in place, then storing text versions of SQL scripts seems like a terrible idea to me.  Unless you simply want a good sample of "how I solved problem x" type files, in which case you would only save relevant scripts?  I have a "useful SQL scripts" collection I take from job to job, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a bunch of metadata in a file name, You can create and manage a 'code table'.  The following table setup is for storing the metadata and SQL code.  If you want to store local .sql files, you can exclude the [sqlcd] field I defined and create your .sql files based on the [id] you create in the table: ie: 1.sql, 2.sql, etc..

```
Create Table CodeCatalog
(
id Int,
func VarChar(200),
targetdb VarChar(200),
targettbls VarChar(400),  --could be placed in a child table using the ID with a child ID
crud VarChar(4),
remarks VarChar(400),
sqlcd VarChar(max)
)
Insert Into CodeCatalog Values
(
1,
'Query Creator Of Password Vars',
'DB1',
'Tables 123 On 456',
'CR',
'return Usernames For Password Records With Values In Them For Inspection',
'Select * From 123 Left Join 456 On 123.id = 456.id'
)
```